# how get directory of pom.xml in java?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have maven project on java. I need to get directory where my pom.xml is. Is it possible to do this in java during run time?

Or maybe there is possibility to get absolute path of my project during runtime?

Actually I have app.property file which is in src/main/resources folder and there is such property: `project.dir = ${pom.basedir}`. Aslo I have log4j.properties file which is in the same folder. Then in code there is such lines to configure log4j:

```
protected static final String log = "./src/main/resources/log4j.properties";
PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyLoader.loadProperty("project.dir") + log);
```

But this does not work, the error is `java.lang.NullPointerException`
, so i can't understand that value has project.dir. What is wrong here?

Comment: Something's telling me that you're trying to do something that's very wrong... what is it that you really want to do?

Comment: Could you tell us the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to run a Java app inside the project directory?

You can scrape by with this during development but it's a bad idea for production use.

I think you would be better off using the *Maven Resources plugin* to copy anything you need from the project to the *output directory* so that they get packaged up in your Jar/War/Ear so that your runtime artifact does not need to know about the project.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/